# Question regarding powering Arduino through the USB Port

Tags: arduino-mega, power, usb

If powering the Arduino (Mega) through the USB port, is a voltage of 5.19VDC acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the ATMEGA328 processor will work without any problem, in fact if you go in the power informations section on the datasheet, you will find that the processor can run from a little less of 3V to a maximum of 5.5V.

Just be careful, because *the processor* works at that power, but *the board* will need from 5 to 5.5V.

Answer (score 0):

That's the approximate expected voltage. The Arduino devices are typically powered at 5V, but the chips themselves are rated to work at values lower and higher than 5V.

Answer (score 0):

The 5.19V you see, I guess you expect 5.00V, is a combination of power supply tolerance and the tolerance of your voltmeter.

Your voltmeter also has some error, we tend to forget that sometimes.